# Mac Access Issues over VPN

Tags: macos, security, terminal, dns, firewall

I can access sites when using browser, but when inside a Mac application I always get "Operation Timed Out" **over VPN**.

Is this a companies firewall issue or my local DNS settings issue? I have been going back and forth with our IT admin team on this. 
With the same firewall roles Windows users are able to run things smoothly.

Few Examples..

**Mac Terminal**

```
himalay$ git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-rest.git
Cloning into 'gs-consuming-rest'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-rest.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

**IDE/IntelliJ/STS**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random":Operation timed out; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:580)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at hello.Application.run(Application.java:22)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:672)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
    ... 14 more
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:81)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:569)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is there a proxy setting in the browser that is giving you access?

Comment: @Gray No, I did not see that anywhere in browsers. I was able to get rid of git clone issue by adding an httpProxy in MacTerminal .bash_profile, but adding the same proxy to my IDE such as STS/IntelliJ does not work :(